# python: get the last matching dictionary from list

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, dictionary, iteration

How to get the last matching dictionary from list of dictionaries:

Example:

```
test_dict={'user'='xxx','tasks':[{'id':'01','age':'60'},{'id':'02','age':'50'},{'id':'01','age':'65'},{'id':'02','age':'65'}]}
```

How do I get the last dict from tasks whose 'id' is '01'?

Do I need to iterate through entire list - test_dict['tasks'] or is there any good approach?

Thanks

Comment: You should at least show us what you have tried so far and how it failed. Hint: go through the list backwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**@Aavik**, you can try the below code.

> I've used **filter()** function to filter the dictionaries with specific keys.
>
> Try the code online at http://rextester.com/URYZW46252 (less efficient way using **filter()** function).
>
> Also try http://rextester.com/HLVQL50077 (using **list comprehension** which is efficient way).

```
def get_last_dict_with_specific_id(test_dict, id):
    # Create tasks list from test_dict
    tasks = test_dict["tasks"]

    # filter tasks list based on dictionaries id i.e get a list of dictionaries with only specific id
    # Update the same list tasks with different content (save space)
    tasks = [d for d in tasks if d["id"] == id]
    # tasks = filter(lambda d: d["id"] == id, tasks) # This is efficient like above one

    # Pick the last dictionary and return it
    if tasks:
        return tasks[len(tasks) - 1]
    else:
        return {}

# TEST    

test_dict = {'user': 'xxx','tasks': [{'id':'01','age':'60'},{'id':'02','age':'50'},{'id':'01','age':'65'},{'id':'02','age':'65'}]};

last_dict_01 = get_last_dict_with_specific_id(test_dict, '01');
print last_dict_01;  # {'age': '65', 'id': '01'}

last_dict_02 = get_last_dict_with_specific_id(test_dict, '02');
print last_dict_02;  # {'age': '65', 'id': '02'}

last_dict_03 = get_last_dict_with_specific_id(test_dict, '03');
print last_dict_03;  # {}
```

Comment: You should consider using a list comprehension instead of `filter` + `lambda`. It's more efficient and (arguably) more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `next` with a generator expression which iterates the list in reverse. If no match is found, the function will return `None`.

```
def get_last(d, val):
    return next((i for i in reversed(d['tasks']) if i['id'] == val), None)

res = get_last(test_dict, '01')

print(res)

{'id': '01', 'age': '65'}
```

Answer (score -1):

This should server your purpose.

```
test_dict={'user':'xxx','tasks':[{'id':'01','age':'60'},{'id':'02','age':'50'},{'id':'01','age':'65'},{'id':'02','age':'65'}]}

id_key = '01'

id_value = {}

tasks = test_dict['tasks']

for i in reversed(tasks):
    if(i['id'] == id_key):
        id_value = i
        break;


print "Found key"      
print id_value
```

Comment: Handle missing value too.